# Perl inheritance - Subroutine override

Tags: perl, inheritance

Is there a way to override `sub a` in `class_1_1` and `class_2_1` with a new behavior(same for both classes) without adding the overridden method to both `class_1_1` and `class_2_1`?

```
package class_0
    sub a
    sub b
1;

package class_1 
    use parent 'class_0'
    sub b
1;

package class_2
    use parent 'class_0'
    sub b
1;

package class_1_1
    use parent 'class_1'
1;

package class_2_1
    use parent 'class_2'
1;
```

Comment: Add a role that provides the method to both classes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One tailor-made solution is to add a [role](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/ETHER/Moose-2.2004/lib/Moose/Manual/Roles.pod) for the wanted behavior.

Here is an example with native OO code, using stand-alone [Role::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Role::Tiny) for roles

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use SomeClass;

my $obj = SomeClass->new;

$obj->a_method;
```

The class `SomeClass.pm`

```
package SomeClass;

use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Role::Tiny::With;  # To "consume" a role. Comes with Role::Tiny

# Consume roles from "AddedRoles.pm"
# That may add or require methods, or override the ones here
with 'AddedRoles';     

sub new { bless { }, $_[0]] }

sub a_method { say "From ", __PACKAGE__ }

1;
```

This role can be added to other classes as well, by adding the `use` statement and the line `with 'AddedRoles';` to them, regardless of their inheritance relationships.  See the docs for ways to fine tune the process.

The package with the roles, `AddedRoles.pm`

```
package AddedRoles;

use feature 'say';  # we get strict and warnings from the package but not this

use Role::Tiny;

# Require that consumers implement methods; Add a method
#require method_1, method_2;    
#sub added_method { say "Adding functionality to consumers" }

# Replace "a_method" in a consumer
around a_method => sub { say "From an overriding role ", __PACKAGE__ } 

1;
```

The `Role::Tiny` need be installed (which has no dependencies).
To replace a method that is defined in the class that consumes the role we need a *method modifier* `around`,<sup>†</sup> provided by [Class::Method::Modifiers](https://metacpan.org/pod/Class::Method::Modifiers), so that is an additional dependency.

Roles are often compared to inheritance, and claimed to provide a nicer and lighter alternative since inheritance is normally "baked" into the whole class hierarchy etc.  However, inheritance generally *specializes* behavior while roles are clearly more flexible; they add or modify behavior (or can specialize for that matter).  I rather see roles fitting nicely somewhere between inheritance and composition.

Note that with roles we can have a near equivalent of multiple inheritance, with almost none of its formidable (and forbidding) headaches.

The bare-bones example above demonstrates the use of `Role::Tiny` on its own. But roles are better utilized along with `Moose` or `Moo` frameworks, using [Moose::Role](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moose::Role) or [Moo:Role](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moo::Role).

I would absolutely recommend to look into these frameworks.  I strongly believe in the value of learning well how to use the Perl's native OO system, but once one has that under their belt it'd be a shame to not try `Moose` or `Moo`.

---

<sup>†</sup> In this particular question though the method to override is *inherited* from another class and in that case there is no need for a modifier.  From ["Role Composition" in docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/Role::Tiny#ROLE-COMPOSITION)

> If a method is already defined on a class, that method will not be composed in from the role. A method inherited by a class gets overridden by the role's method of the same name, though.

So in the case of this question it is enough to normally define a sub in the roles package

```
# In the package that defines roles (like 'AddedRoles' above)
sub a_method  { say "From an overriding role ", __PACKAGE__ }
```

and when this role is consumed by a class *which inherits* `a_method`, like `class_1_1` in the question, the method does get overridden by this one.

Note that if a method is *defined in the class* itself (not inherited) then a role defined as a normal `sub` is quietly ignored (it won't override the method and it won't warn or such).

On the other hand, `around` overrides a method in either case (inherited or defined in the class), but cannot add a method that isn't there at all (and throws an exception if that is attempted).

Comment: In OP's case, I don't think a method modifier is needed. You should be able to just define a sub called `a` in the role. Methods defined in a role will override those which have been inherited from the parent class.

Comment: @tobyink Right, because they want to override an inherited method.  I wanted to show a more generic mechanism, not wanting to get into their inheritance structure (and then forgot about it altogether).  This is a good point, thank you, added a comment.

Comment: @Jean Added a note that relates to your particular circumstance

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with multiple inheritance:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

package class_0;
    sub new {
        my ($class, $foo) = @_;
        return bless{foo=>$foo}, $class;
    }

    sub a {
        my $self=shift;
        print 'a class_0 foo=' . $self->{foo} . "\n";
    }

    sub b {
        my $self=shift;
        print 'b class_0 foo=' . $self->{foo} . "\n";
    }

package new_a;
    sub a {
        my $self=shift;
        print 'a new_a foo=' . $self->{foo} . "\n";
    }

package class_1;
    use parent -norequire, 'class_0';
    sub b {
        my $self=shift;
        print 'b class_1 foo=' . $self->{foo} . "\n";
    }

package class_1_1;
    use parent -norequire, 'new_a', 'class_1';

package class_2;
    use parent -norequire, 'class_0';
    sub b {
        my $self=shift;
        print 'b class_2 foo=' . $self->{foo} . "\n";
    }

package class_2_1;
    use parent -norequire, 'new_a', 'class_2';

package main;

# example usage
my $c0 = class_0->new(1);
my $c1 = class_1->new(2);
my $c2 = class_2->new(3);
my $c11 = class_1_1->new(4);
my $c21 = class_2_1->new(5);

print "-- a class_0 b class_0\n";
$c0->a; $c0->b;
print "-- a class_0 b class_1\n";
$c1->a; $c1->b;
print "-- a class_0 b class_2\n";
$c2->a; $c2->b;
print "-- a new_a b class_1\n";
$c11->a; $c11->b;
print "-- a new_a b class_2\n";
$c21->a; $c21->b;
```

Output:

```
-- a class_0 b class_0
a class_0 foo=1
b class_0 foo=1
-- a class_0 b class_1
a class_0 foo=2
b class_1 foo=2
-- a class_0 b class_2
a class_0 foo=3
b class_2 foo=3
-- a new_a b class_1
a new_a foo=4
b class_1 foo=4
-- a new_a b class_2
a new_a foo=5
b class_2 foo=5
```

Comment: Why not  `use parent -norequire, 'class_1','new_a';`?

Comment: @Jean You'd then get `sub a` via `class_1` (that gets it from `class_0`). I think [this](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl4/porm/ch11_06.htm) describes how it resolves multiple inheritance.

Comment: Now its picking `sub b` from `class_0` instead of `class_1`. But I understand your point.Thanks.(Added `sub b` to question to clarify)

Comment: @Jean You're welcome! If you mix it up too much it'll soon become spaghetti. Multiple inheritance can be tricky (which is why some languages do not allow it). Do you need me to expand on the answer? I added a coment about the new situation.

Comment: When using multiple inheritance, you sometimes want `use mro 'c3';`

Comment: Tip: Convention is to use `$self` for the invocant in Perl

Comment: @ikegami "_Convention is to use `$self` for the invocant in Perl_" -   I knew that in the back of my head. It's been years ... :-)