# Proper Way to Provide Variable to Objects below the present calling subroutine?

Tags: multithreading, perl, oop

In my code base, I have several variables that "live" in the `main` namespace and various modules I utilize can expect to always find in main (for example, `$main::author` is a reference to a hash about the user, `$main::dbh` is the open database handle, `$main::loader` is an object of a core utility class and `$main::FORM` has the processed `QUERY_STRING`). E.g. when the program starts up:

```
$main::author = &getAuthor;
$main::loader = SAFARI::Loader->new;

use SAFARI::View;
my $view = SAFARI::View->new;
$view->output;
```

And then when I'm in `SAFARI::View::output`, I can call on those core variables, e.g.:

```
# Display user name:
$output .= 'Hello, ' . $main::author->{'fullName'} . '! Welcome!';
```

The problem: when the code is running in a threaded environment, one thread may need a different `$loader` object or have a different `$author` logged in than the other thread. More pressingly still, each thread has, of course, a different database handle.

I know I could pass along the core information when creating objects such as `View` by adding parameters it takes. But that means every type of object that presently can just reference these items in the `main` namespace must have a lengthy list of parameters instead. I'm trying to think of the most efficient and "safe" way to solve this problem.

I've considered creating a hash reference that has all the different bits in it within each thread, e.g. `$common` that has `$common->{'FORM'}`, `$common->{'loader'}`, `$common->{'author'}`, etc., and then pass those as a single argument to each object:

```
my $common = #Logic to set up this combination of bits for this particular thread.

my $view = SAFARI::View->new({ 'common' => $common });
my $article = SAFARI::Article->new({ 'common' => $common });
my $category = SAFARI::Category->new({ 'common' => $common });
```

That's not too tedious, but it still seems inefficient; it'd be preferable if the "environment" of *just* that thread could contain something that object within in it could access. As far as I can tell, declaring `our $common` within the subroutine that is run by the thread would do this and any objects created within that subroutine would have access to that variable. Is there any harm in this approach?

It seems like it would be cleaner to have these items in some sort of namespace, but if I refer to, say, `$SAFARI::common`, that name space would reach across threads just like `main` does. Would having `$SAFARI::common` but then declaring a `local` variant of it in each thread be reasonable?

Is there a "best practice" for what I'm trying to do? It's going to take some significant reworking of code to fix this one way or another, so I'd really like to get it "right."

Comment: I'm not sure I get the whole structure-- so `SAFARI::` objects are created in threads and they need access to thread-specific `$common` structure? But that `$common` need initially be made in `main::` (and then it will be customized in each thread as needed) ...?  Correct (-ish) ?

Comment: Yeah, basically -- I may have made it too complicated. Right now those common bits of data that all of my modules need are in `main::`. I'd like to create the equivalent that is local to a particular subroutine (the one called for each thread) so that any objects it creates could access it like they might access `$main::common`, but without the risk of cross-talk between the threads. It could either take the contents of  a hypothetical `$main::common` and create a "fork" of it, so to speak, that was localized to that subroutine or it could be a newly constructed hashref made within the thread.

Comment: I'm imagining roughly equivalent of `$self` in an object, where it is unique to that particular object (and not another object of the same class), but where everything that exists "below" can get to it somehow.

Comment: So you want each thread to get a copy of `$common`, which won't be shared? And then each can "edit" its copy for objects created in that thread?

Comment: Basically. I'm still grasping for quite the right way to put it, maybe this is better: let's say each thread creates a base `SAFARI` object and triggers a method on that object (`initialize`). That method creates a series of objects such as `View`, `Category`, `User`. For example, each of those objects' methods then goes to `$main::common->{'dbh'}` to get the database handle. Instead I'd like them to be able to get that from the particular `SAFARI` object which called them. I'm sorry if I'm making this muddled.

Comment: In Perl, any data structures existing when threads are created are copied to each thread.  That's why it's often a good idea to create threads right up front, before there's too much data in the program, to avoid those threads being too bloated and heavy.  Then, the copied data is *not* shared, by default, in Perl.  So you could just create `$common` in `main::` and create threads after that point and then each thread will have its own copy to do with as it pleases. Would that do it?

Comment: I think that probably would. I was trying to set it up so that even if I just wanted two base `SAFARI` objects co-existing in a non-threaded environment they could still have their own `$common`, but your point really helps and would cover the vast majority of my need at least. I guess I was waiting too long to deal with creating threads in the past. Thank you, @zdim! If you want to put that as an answer, I'll "accept" it.

Comment: I posted, more to have something concrete to talk with.  Let me know how it looks for your need, and we can take it from there. I'll try now to better understand what those `SAFARI::` things need...

Comment: When you say "_a base SAFARI object_" do you actually have an inheritance chain there with the base class being`SAFARI`?  (Or are you using the term in a more casual manner?)

Comment: "_I was trying to set it up so that even if I just wanted two base `SAFARI` objects co-existing in a non-threaded environment they could still have their own `$common`_'  -- yes, can absolutely have that. There can be part of data in the class (attribute) that is populated from `$common`, as oject is created or initialized. So each object has its own and can use `$common` (via `new` or `init` or some such) as needed.

Comment: @zdim So I could somehow create a `SAFARI` object for each instance -- with said bits of data -- and then when I created the various necessary child objects, e.g. `SAFARI::View`, etc., they'd inherit the data from that _particular_ `SAFARI` object? Perhaps the trick would be to create the other objects through a method in `SAFARI` that passed `$common` along and then returned the child class's object?

Comment: If you do have inheritance, just keep in mind that the main point of it is to have more abstract structures/behavior in the base class, which its derived subclasses specialize further.  It's not a tool meant for distributing data/properties.  For that you'd want composition, or roles, for example.

Comment: @zdim Whoops! Sorry, I must have deleted my answer to that. Yes, I'm using inheritance, but I wasn't clear if it would inherit the data from a "generic" `SAFARI` class (what I would have assumed) or the data from the already populated `common` of a particular `SAFARI` object, if that makes sense. E.g. if `SAFARI::View` and `SAFARI::Category` both inherit from `SAFARI` and have that `common` attribute, would there be a way to interlink them so the data stayed the same in both by nature of their shared parent? It sounds like maybe that is a matter for roles (a new subject for me)?

Comment: I apologize -- I'm still being a tad murky with my questions. Let's say for thread one I want to set the `SAFARI` attribute `common->{'dbh'}` to `handle1` and for thread two I want to set the same to `handle2`. I see how I could add a `common->{'dbh'}` attribute and give it a default within `SAFARI`, but I haven't figured out a way to make -- within a particular scope -- set all child classes have an attribute other than some hardcoded default within `SAFARI`. E.g. some imaginary syntax `let all SAFARI::common->{'dbh'} = 'handle2'` before creating all the child objects.

Comment: Right, I got it.  I'll add to the post, it doesn't work so well over comments...

Comment: I've cleaned up a couple of my comments (to one of which your comment refers in a way, sorry). They were out of context and too detailed and unclear. I'll rather add to the answer...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a complex question, with multiple major components.

For starters, there is a question of how to pass an initial data-structure to threads so that they can use it, but without it being shared.

In Perl, when threads are created the existing data are copied to each thread. That's why it's often a good idea to create threads right up front, before there's much data in the program, to avoid those threads being bloated. The copied data is not shared, by default, in Perl.

So you can just create your initial `$common` structure in the `main::` and then create threads, and each will get its own copy of it. Then threads can create their own `SAFARI::` objects and do as they please with the data structure.  A simple demo

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';
use Data::Dump qw(dd pp);

use threads;

my $ds = { val => 10, ra => [ 10..12 ] };

my @threads = map { async(\&proc_ds, $ds) } 1..3;

$_->join() for @threads;

say "main: ", pp $ds;

sub proc_ds {
    my ($ds) = @_; 

    # Modify data in the thread
    $ds->{val} += 10 * threads->tid;
    $_ += $ds->{val} for @{$ds->{ra}};

    say "Thread ", threads->tid, ": ", pp $ds;
}
```

This prints

```
Thread 1: { ra => [30, 31, 32], val => 20 }
Thread 2: { ra => [40, 41, 42], val => 30 }
Thread 3: { ra => [50, 51, 52], val => 40 }
main: { ra => [10, 11, 12], val => 10 }
```

If, instead, you need to share data structures perhaps see [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46703949/4653379), for example.

---

Each thread then needs to use a class hierarchy, whereby multiple subclasses should be initialized the same way using a common data structure modified in each thread.<sup>†</sup>

In Perl's inheritance model, methods gets inherited from the parent class but not data. So the question here is how to nicely populate all subclasses to same data.

There are advanced techniques that may make the process more elegant, but I'd suggest to simply introduce the attribute and define the method in the parent class and then have all subclasses use it to initialize.  That is going to be crystal clear, and as economical as anything else.  Like

```
use SAFARI::View;
use SAFARI::Other;

# ... set/customize $common

my ($sview_obj, $sother_obj) = 
    map { $_->new->init_common($common) } 
        qw(SAFARI::View SAFARI::Other);

say "View object: $sview_obj";  # overload "" (quotes) for this, see below
```

This would be done in each thread, where `$common` is first customized per thread as needed.

There isn't a magical way for the derived classes to pick up *data* from the parent, and you don't want a base class to have to know about its derived classes, in principle.  And there is nothing wrongjk with nicely instantiating all subclasses, much like in the question itself.

The sub `init_common` need only be defined in `SAFARI`, the parent class

**SAFARI.pm** file

```
package SAFARI;

use warnings;
use strict;

sub new {
    my ($class, @args) = @_;
    my $self = {
        common => {},  # introduce the attribute, for clarity
        # ... 
    };
    return bless $self, $class;
}

sub init_common {
    my ($self, $data) = @_; 
    $self->{common}->{dbh} = $data->{dbh};  # etc, populate common
    return $self;
}
...
1;
```

We don't need to specify the attribute in the constructor if it's not being set as it will be created by writing to `$self` reference in `init_common`, but listing it helps clarity. (Of course, `common` attribute can be written at construction <sup>‡</sup> as well; and, we don't need a separate method for it either.)

Derived subclasses need not mention any of this, attribute nor `init_common` method, unless they should customize things.

**SAFARI/View.pm** file

```
package SAFARI::View;

use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';
use Data::Dump qw(pp);

# Make sure @INC gets set as needed
use parent 'SAFARI';

use overload ( q("") => sub { return pp {%$_[0]} } );

# no need for init_common, nor for new (except to modify/override)

sub output { 
    my ($self, @args) = @_;
    say $self->{common}->{...};
    return $self;
};
...
1;
```

---

<sup>†</sup> Inheritance is already in place here, otherwise composition or roles would be good alternatives.  Even so, still consider using a role here; see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63589545/4653379) for instance.

<sup>‡</sup>  If 'common' data can be passed to the constructor

```
sub new {
    my ($class, $attr) = @_;  # pass a hashref with attribute => value
    my $self = {
        common => {},  # introduce the attribute, for clarity
        # ... 
    };
    bless $self, $class;
    $self->init_common( $attr->{common} ) if exists $attr->{common};
    return $self;
}

sub init_common {
    my ($self, $data) = @_; 
    $self->{common}->{$_} = $data->{$_} for keys %$data;
    return $self;
}
```

then 'common' can also be initialized as

```
# ... set/customize $common

my ($sview_obj, $sother_obj) = 
    map { $_->new( { common => $common } ) } 
        qw(SAFARI::View SAFARI::Other);
```

Comment: Thank you!  I think I had my threads too late in the startup before and it was confusing me on this. Does this same principle apply to `require`ing modules, where I'd need to do that _before_ threading starts to avoid them having to be separately processed by each thread?

Comment: @TimothyR.Butler I added a note on classes -- one way to do what is needed (if I got that).  Let me know how it looks, I will surely edit.  As for modules and threads, one needs all `use` statements in a thread, even if they appeared in `main::` already.  Well -- unless it's all in the same file, as in my first example, where I use `Data::Dump::pp` without loading it in the thread.  But that's a bit of an accident; if the thread runs code from a module (which it loads) then needed modules must be `use`d in that module

Comment: @TimothyR.Butler Edited a little, added some comments and tweaked code a little i think, perhaps you want to gloss over it. It's mostly on the fact that what I show (about inheritance) is practically what's in the question, as there's no magic way to make subclasses get data (unless you'd go to "factories" or some such, but that won't be simpler, and you have the inheritance chain already).   Let me know if things aren't clear or are missing ...

Comment: (in case you didn't know-- can review changes to a post by clicking on "edited 11 hours ago"  (or whatever time is), right under the middle of the text -- it's a link that'll show edits, with changes nicely highlighted)

Comment: Wow -- this is amazing -- thank you for all of the pointers. I'm having a bit of a hard time getting my head around the idea of roles (I read your answer on the question you linked to as well), but the way you sketched out handling the situation fits really well with my use case. Thanks again! It does seem like a very clear and economical approach. I already have a subroutine which initializes modules (so it can intelligently pick a subclass or the parent if no subclass is available), so I can incorporate your code into it and it'll be quite nice.

Comment: @TimothyR.Butler Added another way to initialize some data, at construction (it's in a footnote). This is a standard way and I'm sure you know that but I thought I'd let you know about the edit.

Comment: Thanks so much. Your answer has led me to do some serious restructuring of my code for the better, I think!